# New to wordpress having trouble with javascript in the head.php

Tags: javascript, wordpress

So I am new to wordpress. I am trying to get a javascript code I wrote in a separate file to run on my wordpress site. I know the code works because I have used it on other sites. I think I am having problems in my head.php where I call the file. Here is what I have so far.

```
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">  
   <?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
   <?php wp_head(); ?>
   <script type="text/javascript" 
      src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/sticky.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/js/sticky.js"></script>
```

Make sure you have a file called `sticky.js` in `/wp-content/themes/YOUR-THEME-FOLDER/js/`

Answer (score 0):

The `bloginfo("template_url")` only lists the folder path to the template folder. You need to tack on your template's folder and the location of the JavaScript file inside of your template's folder.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/my_template/js/sticky.js"></script>
```